GEOSConcaveHull for 3d
In the GEOS computational geometry library (I use With the API) there is a GEOSConcaveHull function that returns a "concave hull" of a geometry. Is concave hull designed for points in space? If yes, give an example of its use in this case.
Please tell me a library in C (not C++) in which alpha shape 3d and the ball pivoting algorithm would be implemented.
For the case of points lying on a plane, it works well. But if it is used for points in space, it obviously returns the wrong result, but at the same time no error occurs.I set the set of points using the GEOSGeom_create Collection, which contains only GEOS_POINT.
